# Hide form from parent page until specific iframe element ID loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

All I need is to show parent page form only if specific element ID loads inside iframe. parent/iframe are on the same domain. How can I achieve that using javascript?

```
<form id="Search" action="../search.php" target="my-iframe" method="post">
<input type="text" id="location" name="keywords[all_words]"  />
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('Search').submit()" >Search</a>
</form>

<iframe id="myiframe" src="../page.html" name="myiframe" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
// wait for the page to finish loading
window.onload = function(){

    // hide your form
    document.getElementById('Search').style.display = 'none';

    // get the document of the iframe
    var frameDocument = document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow.document;
    // if this is true the element with id 'test' is in the frame
    if(frameDocument.getElementById('test')){
        // show your form
        document.getElementById('Search').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: I get syntax error on console (Null) on :  var frameDocument = document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow.document;       although iframe id is correct.

Comment: You might need to wrap the script code in `window.onload = function(){...}`. You might be getting that error because the iframe hasn't been loaded when the scrip is running.

Comment: You're welcome, remember to accept the answer if it did indeed answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to attach a `load` event to the iframe. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kPqbS/